# flutter_local_notifications not working for me

Tags: flutter, notifications, localnotification

I add `flutter_local_notifications` dependency and setup manifest file (added permission and receives) but notify is not working, do I need more project setting except for the manifest permission for android?

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized **FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin**? If no then try to add below statements in your **initState()** as below

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new 
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    // initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
    onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
}
```

try this and let me know

Comment: Yes, I Initialize it too, I do all required setup but I don't know why it not working...